# Communicate Azure App Service to locally hosted IIS WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, azure-web-app-service, azure-servicebusrelay

I am struggling to make the communication from Azure App service ( WebApp ) to WCF hosted in IIS locally ( OnPrem ).

Previosuly when both apps were deployed on IIS ( ManagementApp, AXYOneServer ) locally, they were able to communicate without any issue.

following url is mainly used to communicate to WCF service which is browseable on IIS without any problem.

http://1xxxsstt1045.forest7.dom/AXYOneServer/AXYFrontendService.svc/FES3

The above url is completely working fine when both apps are locally hosted ( IIS ).
But If app service hosted at azure try to access above url which is osted at IIS , I can see the following exception.

```
 There was no endpoint listening at http://1xxxsstt1045.forest7.dom/AXYOneServer/AXYFrontendService.svc/FES3 that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

What could be the reason?
What should I do to make their communication successfull. Moreover, debugging should also be possible from azure app-service to locally deployed IIS WCF service.

*Internal Exception* : The remote name '1xxxsstt1045.forest7.dom' cannot be resolved.

Comment: There is [a solution for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/service-bus-dotnet-hybrid-app-using-service-bus-relay).

Comment: additional information : The remote name  '1xxxsstt1045.forest7.dom' cannot be resolved :

Comment: I tried to add ip address instead of hostname '1xxxxsstt1045.forest7.dom' as 10.45.124...
But it didnt work. Thrown exception of 

'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.45.124.37:443'

Comment: Do I need to create Hybrid Connection for this task?