# How to debug azureapp service and IIS hosted WCF combinely?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, azure-web-app-service, hybrid

I need to debug WCF services hosted in IIS ( onPrem ) from azure app service. Azure app service ( web-app hosted at azure ) will communicate with IIS hosted WCF service.

How this will be possible ? Because when everything is hosted in IIS(onPrem ) ( app-service and WCF service ), both are running under the same application pool. This way it was quite possible to debug both services at same time.

But Azure appservice is quite different, I can't see the brake points are hitting and enabled in WCF code. How this can be possible? Any way around?

So, azureapp service is on cloud and WCF service is hosted on Prem IIS.

Comment: You can take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67948881/communicate-azure-app-service-to-locally-hosted-iis-wcf-service

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Theobald Du](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13960537/theobald-du). Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

Possible options:

1. go to webconfig page of your site, look for the tag endpoint, and check the port in the address attribute, maybe there was a change in the port number
2. When the request size is bigger than the request size set in IIS as a limit, then you can get that error too.
   Check the IIS request limit and increase it if it's lower than you need.

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437914/there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at-url-that-could-accept-the-message)